# Can I bypass “AppName would like to Use your current location” Message

Tags: cllocationmanager

I want to bypass “AppName would like to Use your current location” message, with "Allowed" state.

Is it possible?

Comment: By "Allowed" I mean "OK". (The other one option is "Don't Allow")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't bypass the message. Your app need to get user's permission to use user's current location.